# Rollback transaction not working properly

Tags: mysql, database, transactions

In database manipulation command such as insert, update or delete can sometime throws exception due to invalid data. To protect the integrity of application data we must make sure when we a transaction was failed we must rollback

```
  PreparedStatement ps = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
          conn = DriverManager.getConnection( URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD );

          String query = "INSERT INTO tbl1(id, username) " +
                "VALUES (?, ?)";
          ps = conn.prepareStatement( query );
          ps.setString( 1, "javaduke" );
          ps.execute();

          query = "INSERT INTO tbl2 (id, tbl1_id, " +
               "quantity, price) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
          ps = conn.prepareStatement( query );
          ps.setInt( 1, id );
          ps.setInt( 2, tbl_id );
          ps.setInt( 3, 10 );
          ps.setDouble( 4, 29.99 );
          ps.execute();
         }
    catch ( SQLException e )
    {
conn.rollback()
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is Java.

Right after you get your connection object, turn off autocommit, like so.

```
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection( URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD );
  conn.setAutoCommit(false);
```

Right after your last `execute()` do this.

```
  conn.commit();
```

Then the `rollback()` in your exception handler should do what you expect.

This should extend the scope of your transaction to beyond a single SQL query.